# HTML5 widget surface

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, html, css, web-applications

I am planning to create a HTML5-based dashboard application allowing to place elements (charts, figures etc.) on a surface at specific positions and different sizes, save the layout in a XML-structure and load it later on.

Therefore I am searching for a surface similar to the Android-desktop or the WPF-Grid for layouting but some kind of HTML5 implementation. 
This means the surface should offer a tabular layout where elements can be positioned. The elements snap the the tabular's grid and can be resized by using row- or column-span. 
For the grid it should be defineable how many rows and columns are available. The rows and columns should spread evenly across the surface and should scale with its size.

I am kind of new to web development and stuck with this requirement being not able to find some adequat solution. I am using asp.net mvc 4. I found dashboard like solutions like this one: http://www.dynamicdashboards.net/ 
..but it feels pretty heavy-weight.

Have you guys already solved similar problems? Have you got some suggestions of how to implement such a requirement with HTML5 technologies?

I am thankful for every hint or links of how to solve this!

Comment: For everyone having a similar problem: There is some proposal at the W3C for such a CSS-layouting: http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-grid-layout/. The problem is it seems to be supported very poorly by the various browsers. For the moment we are trying to solve this by arranging div elements by hand.